# Spring Boot repackage target OutOfMemoryError

Tags: spring-boot

When I do `mvn package` every thing is successful. I can see the JAR and required dependencies are in place. But when I try to run the generated JAR,It waits for a while and complains `OutOfMemoryError`

My POM

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Your application is out of memory, not the Maven plugin. I think you need to share some  more code (probably a complete project that reproduces the problem).

Comment: Neither my application not maven is out of memory. My application runs fine if I do `mvn spring-boot:run`. When I do `mvn package` the build is successful and I can see the generated JAR.
I have two projects. Both have same problem. I can share one of them. What do you want to see ?

Comment: The whole project would be useful (e.g. a link to a github repo).

Comment: have you set `MAVEN_OPTS`?

Comment: @cfrick No I did not use the OPTS. Can you please inform me which flags I should use ?

Comment: @DaveSyer please see the project at https://github.com/kranthi117/deployment

Comment: OK, so how do I break it (starts up fine from java -jar)?

Comment: @kranthi117 i only wanted to know, if you have set MAVEN_OPTS to larger memory settings than the java default, which would explain such a behaviour.  just a shot in the dark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble guys.

I was using `mvn clean install package` instead of `mvn clean package` hence the problem. Silly me.

Comment: That *is* actually a bug in the Boot Maven tooling. But also a pilot error (no need to run package twice), and with Boot 1.1.4 it's better behaved (still an exception but not OOM), so I suggest you upgrade anyway.

Comment: Thanks @DaveSyer I'll do that now